# Primitive element theorem for division rings extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

Assume that $A \subseteq B$ are division $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Further assume that $A$ has the IBN property (does a division ring 'automatically' have the invariant basis number property?).

One version of the [primitive element theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem) says that a finite separable field extension $F \subseteq E$ has a primitive element, namely, there exists an element $e_0 \in E$ such that $E=F(e_0)$.

Now, according to the comments in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424025/dimension-of-division-rings-extension#comment5010707_2424025), the rank of $B$ as an $A$-module is well-defined.

> Is there an analogue theorem to the primitive element theorem for such division algebras?

Namely, if $A \subseteq B$ has finite rank and if it is 'separable',
then there exists $b \in B$ such that $B=A[b]$ (the finiteness of rank implies that $b$ is 'left' algebraic over $A$).

I am not sure if I know what 'separable' should mean. There is the notion of a separable algebra over a commutative algebra. It is easy to see that a division algebra $D$ over a field $k$ is separable, since the kernel of the canonical map $D \otimes_k D \to D$, $d_1 \otimes_k d_2 \mapsto d_1d_2$,
is zero. Therefore, each of $A$ and $B$ is separable over $k$. What should be the meaning for $B$ separable over $A$?

Any comments are welcome!

Comment: *does a division ring 'automatically' have the invariant basis number property?* Yes. The proof is the same as the fact that finite dimensional vector spaces have a unique dimension.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I suspected. Please, do you know if a division ring is staby finite? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stably_finite_ring

Comment: At the article you cite, it says:  *noetherian rings and artinian rings are stably finite*, and that *does* include division rings. Did you read it? In fact it could say one-sided Noetherian or one-sided Artinian.

Comment: The answer is yes, since  a division ring is Noetherian (it has no one-sided ideals other than 0 and itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a theorem of this sort.  In particular, consider $k=A=\mathbb{R}$ and $B=\mathbb{H}$.  Then $B$ is a separable algebra over $k=A$ (there is no question of what this means since $A$ is commutative), but it does not have a primitive element.  More generally, if $k$ is any field and $B$ is a finite dimensional noncommutative division algebra whose center is $k$, then $B$ is a separable $k$-algebra but cannot have a primitive element over $k$ (otherwise it would be commutative!).

Comment: Thanks! I like your answer, but I still wonder what happens if $A$ is non-commutative. Anyway, in the special case of rank two, is there a primitive element?

Comment: Yes. just take any element of $B\setminus A$ and it obviously must be primitive.

Comment: More generally, in the special case of rank prime number, also $B=A[b]$, for every $b \in B-A$; this follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2428065/multiplicativity-formula-for-a-tower-of-division-algebras/2428196#2428196. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.